# Missing entry issue (ClearMyTrackByProcess)

Tags: c#

I have a small application in vs c# on the button event I want clear the browser history etc

> System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(“rundll32.exe”,
>   “InetCpl.cpl,CleanMyTracksByProcess 1″);

But I am getting this error :

```
error in IntelCpl.cpl
missing entry: ClearMTrackByProcess
```

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: There are a couple spelling errors in your code and erorr message - can you clarify which you are using?  You have `CleanMyTracksByProcess` in your code example (it should be `ClearMyTracksByProcess` and in your output you are showing `IntelCpl.cpl` instead of `InetCpl.cpl`, and `ClearMTrackByProcess` instead of `ClearMyTracksByProcess`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think your problem is you need

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(“rundll32.exe”, “InetCpl.cpl.CleanMyTracksByProcess 1″);
```

you have a "," instead of a "."

also you might meant "Clear" and not "Clean"

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(“rundll32.exe”, “InetCpl.cpl.ClearMyTracksByProcess 1″);
```

Comment: Thank you so much all of you